# How can i have a laravel controller accept POST data or a variable?

Tags: laravel, controller

I am trying to write a controller that will allow me to either pass post data from an AJAX call or data from another function to it. How can I acheive that?

Web.php

```
Route::post('myFunction',[App\Http\Controllers\MyClass::class, 'myFunction']);
```

Class.php

```
class MyClass extends BaseController {
   // In laymen's terms:
   public static function myFunction(Request $request , $someVar = null) 
   {
     if ($request->isMethod('POST')){
         //do thing 1
     }else{
         //do thing 2
     }
   }
}
```

with that code, when i try to send $someVar, I get:

```
Argument #1 ($request) must be of type Illuminate\\Http\\Request, string given.
```

***----Rewrite---***

Let me explain it better. I apologize..

When a user goes to mysite.com, it is routed to main().

main calls a bunch of things, but what we care about is below.

```
class MyClass extends BaseController
    public static function main(){
       $var = MyClass::myFunction($someVar);
    }

    public static function myFunction($someVar){
        //do a thing
    }
}
```

on that page is a dropdown, and if the user changes the drop down, an ajax post request is made using the route:

```
Route::post('/xyz',[App\Http\Controllers\MyClass::class, 'myFunction']);
```

so the variable coming into myFunction could either be the post request, or passed from main()

Comment: `Request $request` is available on _every Controller method_, and if you need an optional variable, you'd do `myFunction(Request $request, $someVar = null)`. Then you simply check `if ($someVar)` (`isset()` is incorrect, since it is set by being declared in the Method, `if ($someVar)` just checks if it is not `null`). If you need to check if a `POST` was made, you can do `if ($request->isMethod('POST')) { ... }`, or `$request->method() == 'POST'`, etc.

Comment: see the edits i just made.

Comment: That doesn't show how you're trying to use this Method... I assume this isn't hooked up to a `Route`? If not, you'd likely call this via `MyClass::myFunction(request())` **OR** `MyClass::myFunction(request(), $someVar)`. Again, `Request $request` can and is "injected" if this Method is used by a `Route`, but if you're calling this method directly, you need to pass `request()` (or `$request` if it's available) to the method.

Comment: made another edit.  I am using the routes.php

Comment: Then why is this method `static`? Also, `Route::post('myFunction', ...)` will never populate `$someVar`... You'd need something like `Route::post('myFunction/{someVar?}', ...)`, then a `POST` to `/myFunction` or `/myFunction/someVar`, etc. See Route Parameters: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters

Comment: hopefully added more detail. sorry about the vagueness.

Comment: Still vague... Why is `myFunction` static? `$someVar` still cannot be populated from `Route::post('/xyz', ...)`, there's no Route Parameter. And I've already shown how you call this method with `request()` and/or `$someVar`. You'll have to put the pieces together to make this work.

Comment: WHY are you using static methods as your controller methods?